# Splitting a PCA plot by groups

Tags: r, plot, pca

I found this plot in the internet:

[image]

Which is mainly splitting the PCA plot by groups. Do you know if there is a package in R that can do something similar?

Comment: Similar result (non 3D) might be achieved using `facet_wrap` from `ggplot2` while using same variable for facets and color points.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for a 3D version